# Spring Cloud Feign with OAuth2RestTemplate

Tags: spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud

I'm trying to implement Feign Clients to get my user info from the user's service, currently I'm requesting with oAuth2RestTemplate, it works. But now I wish to change to Feign, but I'm getting error code 401 probably because it doesn't carry the user tokens, so there is a way to customize, if Spring support for Feign is using, a RestTemplate so I can use my own Bean?

Today I'm implementing in this way

**The service the client**

```
@Retryable({RestClientException.class, TimeoutException.class, InterruptedException.class})
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "getFallback")
public Promise<ResponseEntity<UserProtos.User>> get() {
    logger.debug("Requiring discovery of user");
    Promise<ResponseEntity<UserProtos.User>> promise = Broadcaster.<ResponseEntity<UserProtos.User>>create(reactorEnv, DISPATCHER)
            .observe(Promises::success)
            .observeError(Exception.class, (o, e) -> Promises.error(reactorEnv, ERROR_DISPATCHER, e))
            .filter(entity -> entity.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful())
            .next();
    promise.onNext(this.client.getUserInfo());
    return promise;

}
```

**And the client**

```
@FeignClient("account")
public interface UserInfoClient {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/uaa/user",consumes = MediaTypes.PROTOBUF,method = RequestMethod.GET)
    ResponseEntity<UserProtos.User> getUserInfo();
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Feign doesn't use a `RestTemplate` so you'd have to find a different way. If you create a `@Bean` of type `feign.RequestInterceptor` it will be applied to all requests, so maybe one of those with an `OAuth2RestTemplate` in it (just to manage the token acquisition) would be the best option.

Comment: Thanks @Dave, creating a bean of `RequestInterceptor` and setting the Bearer token from the oauth on RequestTemplate header worked

Comment: Great. Maybe you could contribute it back to spring-cloud-security?

Comment: Yea, sure, I'll raise a ticket on GitHub, so we can discuss it there

Comment: Hi Joao, thanks for your contribution. I have the same problem, but I don't get your solution to work, maybe you could take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32185734/spring-cloud-feign-with-oauth2

Answer (score 7):

this is my solution, just to complement the another answer with the source code, implementing the interface feign.RequestInterceptor

```
@Bean
public RequestInterceptor requestTokenBearerInterceptor() {
    return new RequestInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public void apply(RequestTemplate requestTemplate) {
            OAuth2AuthenticationDetails details = (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails)
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails();

            requestTemplate.header("Authorization", "bearer " + details.getTokenValue());
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I used a concrete implementation, so I could avoid null pointers and sending the token to an unprotected resource in case the request does not contain a token or an authenticated user, since for now we can't customize per client interceptor. If you are interested you can check it here: https://github.com/crly/commons/blob/master/src/main/java/io/curly/commons/config/feign/OAuth2FeignRequestInterceptor.java

Comment: good solution!.. in my scenery (one resource server requesting another) a authenticated user/token is always required. thanks for share!

Comment: Just to add my two cents: It's important to configure the sessionCreationPolicy at least to "IF_REQUIRED" as the SecurityContext will be empty otherwise =) Thanks for this solution, finally got token relay with feign

Comment: Can this be used with Hystrix?

Comment: Sure! I'am using with Hystrix here

Comment: This solution failed with Hystrix, I do not know why your code works. With Hystrix, it faled to get request context. Because isolation strategy of Hystrix is THREAD, the request context cannot be retrieved from Threadlocal.

Comment: for hystrix, you need this `hystrix.shareSecurityContext=true`.