# Spring boot Oauth2 : Token relay from a client using Feign, Ribbon, Zull and Eureka to a ressource

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-feign

I have an oauth2 client that get a token from an authorization server successfully. (not always has been the case but now it is... :))

The client, the zuul gateway and the resource server are all registered in Eureka.

My client use a Proxy to access to a remote ressource service named microservice-files.

```
@RestController
@FeignClient(name = "zuul-server")
@RibbonClient(name = "microservice-files")

public interface ProxyMicroserviceFiles {

    @GetMapping(value = "microservice-files/root")
    FileBean getUserRoot();

}
```

So I'd like to relay the token to Zull and then to the resource server.

I can relay the token this way to contact Zuul and apparently the load balancing is managed too (I've just test I didn't know and it's great) also zuul can relay the token, but it's not very convenient I'd prefer the previous approach.

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients("com.clientui")
public class ClientUiApplication {

    @Bean
    public OAuth2RestOperations restOperations(
            OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource, 
            OAuth2ClientContext context) {

        return new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource, context);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(ClientUiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

here is the test controler

```
@Controller
public class ClientController {

    @Autowired
    private RestOperations restOperations;

    @RequestMapping("/root")
    public ResponseEntity userRootTest() {

       String rootUrl = "http://localhost:9004/microservice-files/root";

       return  restOperations.getForEntity(rootUrl,FileBean.class);

    }

}
```

Comment: Find the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29439653/spring-cloud-feign-with-oauth2resttemplate/ the answer is a litle bit old (3 years ago) but it still work perfectly. I don't know if a better solution more recent exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I correctly understand your problem then you can use a RequestInterceptor to add a token in each request by the feign. In order to do it you can use the next configuration:

```
@Bean
public RequestInterceptor oauth2FeignRequestInterceptor(OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext,
                                                        OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource) {
    return new OAuth2FeignRequestInterceptor(oauth2ClientContext, resource);
}

@Bean
protected OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource() {
    AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails resource = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
    resource.setAccessTokenUri("http://127.0.0.1:9000/auth/login");
    resource.setUserAuthorizationUri("http://127.0.0.1:9000/auth/authorize");
    resource.setClientId("my-client");
    resource.setClientSecret("my-secret");
    return resource;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer it works perfectly. I don't know which one is the best solution . The other one just add the Token in the header, it is relayed and finaly the resource server can check it. Here we contact the authorization server at each feign request in the client I guess.

Comment: OAuth2FeignRequestInterceptor does not try to obtain a new token on each feign requests, this is implementation obtain a token only if it misses in the OAuth2ClientContext, then put this token in context and refresh token only when it expired. 
You do not need to worry about performance in this case.

Comment: Ok so if the other solution doesn't refresh the token if necessary; this is the best  solution :) thanks for your contribution

Comment: Is there a way, We could use Eureka discovered name instead of hardcoding:

resource.setAccessTokenUri("http://127.0.0.1:9000/auth/login"); //hard coded
resource.setAccessTokenUri("http://oauth-server/auth/login"); // Eureka Discovered
.
.

If I try Eureka Discovered name(oauth-server), I get error: UnknownHostException

Comment: @Hamid I think, this is another problem, and unfortunately isn't simple to solve. I hope this will help: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-security/issues/61

Comment: Thanks Anatoliy. Mentioned solution didn't work for me. I added Interceptor to make it work. My solution I have posted below.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to make it work.

```
 @Bean(name = "oauth2RestTemplate")
    @LoadBalanced
    public OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate(SpringClientFactory clientFactory) {
        OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails());
        RibbonLoadBalancerClient ribbonLoadBalancerClient = new RibbonLoadBalancerClient(clientFactory);
        LoadBalancerInterceptor loadBalancerInterceptor = new LoadBalancerInterceptor(ribbonLoadBalancerClient);
        ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider accessTokenProvider = new ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider();
        accessTokenProvider.setInterceptors(Arrays.asList(loadBalancerInterceptor));
        restTemplate.setAccessTokenProvider(accessTokenProvider);

        return restTemplate;
    }

    public ClientCredentialsResourceDetails resourceDetails() {
        ClientCredentialsResourceDetails clientCredentialsResourceDetails = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
        clientCredentialsResourceDetails.setId("1");
        clientCredentialsResourceDetails.setClientId("my-ms");
        clientCredentialsResourceDetails.setClientSecret("123");
        clientCredentialsResourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri("http://oauth-server/oauth/token");
        clientCredentialsResourceDetails.setScope(Arrays.asList("read"));
        clientCredentialsResourceDetails.setGrantType("client_credentials");
        
        return clientCredentialsResourceDetails;
    }
```