# Spring boot : Feign client rest call not working with oauth2, but does work on browser

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, access-denied, feign

Having 2 microservices, one rest service one is websocket service. Websocket service has feign client to talk to the rest service.

When calling rest service from a browser tool (postman eg) the call works correctly. We pass only the header `Authorization` with value `Bearer XXXXX`

When calling from feign without interceptor we get a 401: unauthorized, which is correct behaviour.

When adding this interceptor to the codebase, were as XXXXX is the real token of course, we receive a 403

```
@Component
public class FeignOauth2Interceptor implements RequestInterceptor {
    private static final String AUTHORIZATION_HEADER = "Authorization";   
    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
        SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        Authentication authentication = 
        securityContext.getAuthentication();
        template.header(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, "Bearer XXXXX");
    }
}
```

The interceptor is called as we see a different error code after adding it, we went from 401 to 403.

What are we missing here ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not a good idea the hardcoding of your token in the interceptor, you can get a token from the **OAuth2AuthenticationDetails**:

```
@Bean
public RequestInterceptor requestTokenBearerInterceptor() {

    return new RequestInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public void apply(RequestTemplate requestTemplate) {
            Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            if(authentication == null) return;
            OAuth2AuthenticationDetails details = (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) authentication.getDetails();
            requestTemplate.header("Authorization", "Bearer " + details.getTokenValue());                   
        }
    };
}
```

Also, you can use the **OAuth2FeignRequestInterceptor**, which get your token from a context and refresh it itself when it's needed. In my opinion, this is a better solution. You can find an example of using it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53454703/10697598

Comment: Thnx for the help. The code is not final, I use indeed the OAuth2AuthenticationDetails. The problem was a wrong url, feign appears to send a 403 when the endpoint is not found.